# cmder virtualenv name showing

Tags: python, django, command-line-interface, cmder

I am new to cmder, when ever I try to create virtualenv for python, django and activate it using `./Scripts/activate`

This is cmder :

```
F:\python\django\tweeter
λ .\Scripts\activate

F:\python\django\tweeter
λ
```

This is Git bash :

```
Ahmed@DESKTOP-VJ37FJE MINGW64 /f/python/django/tweeter
$ source ./Scripts/activate
(tweeter)
Ahmed@DESKTOP-VJ37FJE MINGW64 /f/python/django/tweeter
$
(tweeter)
Ahmed@DESKTOP-VJ37FJE MINGW64 /f/python/django/tweeter
$
```

As you can see when I use Git bash, it shows me virtualenv name when I activate it. But it not goes same for cmder.

Comment: try set virtualenv name by hand. Here is tutorial:<br><br>
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87062/how-to-display-the-name-of-the-current-virtualenv

Comment: I do not think that is the problem, because it is working absolutely fine with git bash, I wanted to cmder but problem is there...